# How should I write the ActiveRecord when there are multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

The models are like this:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'Customer', :foreign_key => 'buyer_customer_id' 
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'Customer', :foreign_key => 'user_customer_id'
  belongs_to :currency
end  

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :as_buyer_in_contracts, :class_name => 'Contract', :foreign_key => 'buyer_customer_id'  
  has_many :as_user_in_contracts, :class_name => 'Contract',:foreign_key => 'user_customer_id'  
end

class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contracts
end
```

And below is the data:

```
Contract
+----+-------------------+------------------+-------------+
| id | buyer_customer_id | user_customer_id | currency_id |
+----+-------------------+------------------+-------------+
|  1 |         1         |        3         |      3      |
|  2 |         2         |        2         |      2      |
|  3 |         2         |        1         |      2      |
|    |                   |                  |             |


Customer
+----+-------------------+
| id |       name        |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 |    Terry Brown    |
|  2 |    Tom Green      |
|  3 |    Kate White     |
|    |                   |

Currency
+----+-------------------+
| id |       name        |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 |        EUR        |
|  2 |        USD        |
|  3 |        JPY        |
|    |                   |
```

And now I want to find all contracts which signed with customer named "Terry", like this:

```
Contract.where("customers.name like '%Terry%'").includes(:buyer,:user)
#I want 1 and 3, but it can only get 1
Contract.where("customers.name like '%Terry%'").includes(:user, :buyer)
#If I write "user" before "buyer", then I can only get 3
```

Someone told me it can work like this:

```
Contract.join(:customer).where("customers.name like '%terry%'").includes(:user,:buyer)
#It works fine.
```

I tried and it does work. But further when the Contract model belongs_to other model, such as currency_id, the method above cannot work again.

```
Contract.join(:customer).where("customers.name like '%terry%'").includes(:currency, :user, :buyer)
#>>Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'customers_contracts.id' in 'field list': ...
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're not supposed to use joins in conjonction with includes. It hasn't been emphasized enough (and there's no warning in rails) but

> **select, joins, group, having, etc. DO NOT WORK WITH includes!**

You might get results but only by chance. And the odds are it'll break sooner than later.

It seems there's also some inconsistency with includes...

If you need to use a conventional outer join with activerecord >= 3.0 (which is the case here) use the excellent [squeel gem.](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) It really yields the power of Arel.

Try out (with squeel installed) :

```
Contract.joins{buyer.outer}.joins{user.outer}.where("name like '%terry%'")
```

The out of the box join does inner joining only, which excludes non intersecting table, making your goal impossible here : buyer & user can be mutually exclusive...

Comment: NOT WORK? I did use them together in other cases, you mean it may break at any time?

Comment: This is a good candidate for the root of the problem, but your answer is a bit vague at the beginning (select, etc not working with includes, inconsistency). Could you add a clearer explanation of these points and/or point to an authoritative explanation?

Comment: still on holidays... will try to back up my answer a little when I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using joins :buyer or :user instead of :customer?

your Contract model has no :customer attribute/relation

```
Contract.join(:buyer).where("customers.name like '%terry%'").includes(:currency, :user, :buyer)
```

my guess is that will be equivalent to something like

```
Contract.join("INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = contracts.buyer_customer_id").where("customers.name like '%terry%'").includes(:currency, :user, :buyer)
```

check your log file to see exactly what sql is being generated in each case - log/development.log

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the model relation...And the log file is about 40 or 50 lines because my actual condition is very complex. I was totally confused by them.